# Runtime cpu detection in dynamic linker (ld.so)

Tags: c, linux, optimization, linker

I want to integrate a runtime CPU Dispatch into my library. I have several version of some functions, optimized for sse2/sse3/avx and a x87 generic variant. I want to compile all versions into single .so library and I think how to implement a cpu dispatcher.

A fastest way as I think, is to get cpu dispatching at linking step (dynamic linking), so when ld.so will load my library, I want it to check, does cpu supports sse2, sse3 or avx, and then I want ld.so to select right set of functions.

For example (using [gcc target attribute](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Function-Attributes.html#Function-Attributes)):

Library:

```
float* func3_generic(float *a, float *b)  __attribute__ ((__target__ ("fpmath=387")));
float* func3_sse2(float *a, float *b)  __attribute__ ((__target__ ("sse2")));
float* func3_sse3(float *a, float *b)  __attribute__ ((__target__ ("sse3")));
float* func3_avx(float *a, float *b)  __attribute__ ((__target__ ("avx")));
```

I want to have some special symbol `func3()`, which will be setted by linker (ld.so) to the most advanced of `func3_generic`, `func3_sse2`, `func3_sse3`, `func3_avx`. So, if the cpu is Core i7-xxxx, I want that every call to func3 will be the call to func3_avx, and if cpu is PentiumPro, call to func3 will be call to the func3_generic.

At same time I want not to write a lot of dispatching code manually and I want the right variant selected with minimum overhead (no extra indirect jump). This means that I can afford extra time in application startup, but no anything extra in calling this function (there are very high number of calls in some cases).

UPDATE. Linker can do dispatching based on AUXV vector, `AT_HWCAP:` field:

```
$ LD_SHOW_AUXV=1 /bin/echo
...
AT_HWCAP:    fpu ... mmx fxsr sse sse2
```

Comment: Good article from IBM for power platform, https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/wikis/display/LinuxP/Optimized+Libraries  And gnu_indirect_function (or [STT_GNU_IFUNC](http://vger.kernel.org/~davem/cgi-bin/blog.cgi/2010/02/07))  look very promising

Comment: yes, that's what STT_IFUNC is for (which, incidentally, seems to be the first extension that required to change the ABI field of Linux's ELF executables).

Comment: ninjalj, can you add STT_IFUNC as answer and say little more how it works and why it requires change of ABI Fieldo?

Comment: https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/wikis/display/LinuxP/Optimized+Libraries is a dead link now unfortunately.

Answer (score 1):

… Would it be acceptable to simply load one of several `.so`'s using `dlopen`? You could query the CPU type in any of a variety of methods and then choose the appropriate library to bind `func3`

Comment: I need only some functions to be compiled in different way. And I need rather many variants.

Comment: I'm frightened to think of doing this, myself, but it sounds rather like what you want to do is alter the linker's resolution of the Procedure Linkage Table at runtime … ? There's an example of doing so at http://www.apriorit.com/our-company/dev-blog/181-elf-hook … but I'd personally be afraid of it :-)

Comment: slightly different(?) version of that article http://www.codeproject.com/KB/library/elf-redirect.aspx?display=Print

Answer (score -1):

How about an array of function pointers and then use the CPUID instruction to get them to point at the specific implementations at startup. The number of cycles this will cost to do at startup should be miniscule.

Another approach if you really want to avoid any startup costs is to write another small program that queries your CPU about its capabilities and then constructs a command-line for gcc with some macros defined so that only certain function implementations will be compiled.

[CPUID instruction](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CPUID)

Comment: "array of function pointers" is not a method for library. I need to export function just like it is normal.

Comment: I believe that @James was meaning to make `func3()` analogous to `static (float* fnPtr)(float*,float*) = NULL; if (NULL == fnPtr) fnPtr = set_up_pointer(); return *fnPtr(a,b);` … but that would be the extra indirect jump you referred-to?

Comment: `static (float* fnPtr)` is not compatible to usual library interface.

Answer (score -1):

It may be that I'm not following your reasoning. To me it seems that there are better places to do this kind of thing than in the linker. As I see it - though it may not be true in your case - programs are often built on one machine and executed on another/others. For that reason the CPU of the build machine is usually unimportant.

If you're targeting a CPU with specific features there will probably be generic compiler optimizations for that CPU which you will want to take advantage of. For this reason it seems less than optimal to have an application module which is compiled for all (or one specific) CPUs which you link with libs that are CPU-specific. Command line #defines can be used to make the compiler rename func3 to the appropriate run-time function. This will cause the linker to produce a smaller program or references fewer dlls (if your libs are placed there).

The test can also be performed at run-time as suggested previously. If func3 is a pointer that initially points to a certain (generic) function you can overwrite it depending on what your examination of CPUID resulted in. The overhead for this will occur during initialization and there is no adverse performance effect during subsequent execution. The downside is that the .exe will be larger as it needs to contain all available variants of the function.

To actually perform the linking you require I suggest you write a small command-line program that returns an exit code which is dependent on the CPU which the program detects. This exit code is then interpreted in the make file to select (copy) the appropriate library.

Comment: `If func3 is a pointer` is not a pointer; it is function in the library. And the library will be used at various PCs. I should keep the library interface, so I can't make func3 to be a pointer. Also, I talk not about linking step at library build (the `ld` command), but about runtime linker (`ld.so`). It is the time of dynamic libraries loading, just when application is started. I want not to have 10 or 20 precompiled versions of the library, because not every function in the library has cpu-tuned version.

Comment: If your app refers to all the function variants (for example in a pointer vector so the static linker doesn't optimize them out) your app can determine via CPUID (for example) which variant should be used and place the reference to it in a pointer variable which func3 can access. Or have func3 reference the variants through a switch (C) where the appropriate index was determined at startup using CPUID.